# ASP MVC 3 Display List<> Name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i have this model

```
public class Registro
    {
      [DisplayName("Provincia")]
      [Required]
      public int ProvinciaID { get; set; }
      public List<Provincia> rProvincia { get; set; }
    }
```

Now what i need to do for show the Name of `List<Provincia> rProvincia` in my detalis view?, i was thinking that maybe `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.rProvincia.Name)`, any idea?, 
Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 6):

No need to write any `foreach` loops. In your main view simply:

```
@model AppName.Models.Registro
...   
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.rProvincia)
...
```

and then inside the display template `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Provincia.cshtml`:

```
@model AppName.Models.Provincia
<div>
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)
</div>
```

This display template will be rendered for each item in the `rProvincia` collection.

Comment: Thanks Darin Dimitrov, it's not working for me, i don't know if i was wrong, just i need to show in this moment one "rProvincia.Name", ...that work for show just one or show all items of the List? (im working with details view)

Sorry with my english

Comment: @Asinox, I am afraid I don't understand what you mean nor what is not working. The idea is that your main view is strongly typed to the `Registro` view model. Then inside this main view you use the `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.rProvincia)` helper where `rProvincia` is your collection. Then ASP.NET MVC will look for `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Provincia.cshtml` and it will render it for each element of the collection. That's how templated helpers work.

Comment: @Darin im sorry, im new about asp mvc, i did it like you said, but is showing nothing

Comment: @Asinox, does the `rProvincia` list contain any elements? Also make sure that your display template is named exactly as I showed (`Provincia.cshtml`) and that it is situated inside the `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates` folder.

Comment: Well my friend :), i have all like you say :), but nothing happen yet... yes i have elements in rProvincia...

Comment: @Asinox, what ascx are you talking about? Aren't you using the Razor view engine?

Answer (score -3):

FIX:

```
public class Registro
    {
      [DisplayName("Provincia")]
      [Required]
      public int ProvinciaID { get; set; }
      public virtual Provincia rProvincia { get; set; }
    }
```

with virtual i got it

Comment: You should mark @Darin's answer as correct as this was the correct fix for your answer. Ypur fix was a model error on your part which meant your list was not being populated.